# Changing a font-family in an same-domain IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an IFrame that is referencing a file on the same domain, no issues. Through JavaScript, I can change the font-size, color, everything. Except for the font-family. Very weird. It will let me change all properties, but the family, which is what I need!

```
function changeFont()
    {
        var x = document.getElementById("image");
        var y = x.contentDocument;
        y.body.style.fontSize = "20px";
        y.body.style.color = "red";
        y.body.style.fontFamily = "Algerian";
    }

<iframe onload="changeFont()" id="image" width="100%" height="400" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/temp.txt")"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you sure its accessing the font file properly? You either have to have the font file locally or you have to have correctly referenced it via an include (sorry if you already know that)

Comment: If you're doing an include, you could share that code to help us help you out more. You said "I have an iframe that is referencing a file on the same domain" which is quite vague. Which domain, the domain of the iframe, or the domain of the parent page? Also, what file are you talking about? It's pretty obvious that your iframe might be referencing "a" file ;)

Comment: Do you have a custom font family named Algerian?  Try replacing Algerian with something you're sure you have (like monospace) and see if it works then.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that the font file is being access, the contents show up. I have changed the FontFamily many times to different things, but it won't change. I just used algerian this last time because it's hard to mistake it. But, no fonts will work. The color will change, the size will change, but the family won't. Also, yes the file is stored locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by having to learn and use encodings. For the particular font, I had to use a Windows encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To change the `font-family` property you have to do something like this because of the hyphen.

```
function changeFont()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("image");
    var y = x.contentDocument;
    y.body.style.fontSize = "20px";
    y.body.style.color = "red";
    y.body.style["font-family"] = "Algerian";
}
```

Comment: No, that still doesn't change it. Very frustrating!

Comment: Well that worked for me... have you tried adding `!important` to the rule to see if it's because of a conflicting style? Also what browser are you testing this in?

Comment: I'm testing it with I.E. 11. Also, how can I add important, where would that go?

Comment: `y.body.style.setProperty("font-family","Algerian","important");`

Comment: That still won't change it. Every now and then I do get a javascript error, 'F2194'. But, only every now and then.

Comment: And you're positive the other styles are being set? Changing your code to set the color to blue instead of red definitely works?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. I know this is a very difficult question.

Comment: Alright I'm assuming since you know how to see javascript errors in the console, you know how to use the IE DOM inspector correct? If so, highlight the body of the page inside the iframe and see what inline styles are being applied.

Comment: All 3 are being applied, but it's still rendered with no font-family styling. Sorry, by all 3 I mean the color, size, and font-family are being set. Yet the result does not display the font family.

Comment: Well if `font-family` is set for the body, then the code is working like it should. If you don't see that font-family being applied to child elements of the body, that's because there must be a css rule that is more specific to those children elements, that will always override css rules applied to parent elements (i.e. the body). You will either need to set the `font-family` for every element in the body that you want to have that font, or will need to make a css rule and inject that into a style tag in the head of the page.

Comment: Well, the styles tab from the DOM inspector only shows those inline styes, inherited from body. That's all.

Comment: Okay, it's being rendered through a pre tag.